# ArrayList element to integer variable

Tags: java, arraylist, int

I would like to split a String and put every elements in an ArrayList. Then afterwards, take any number of the ArrayList and put it in a integer variable. This is my code:

```
String eq = "4/2+3*4*2-1";

String[] eqList = eq.split("(?<=[+*-/])|(?=[+*-/])");

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < eqList.length; i++) {
    list.add(eqList[i]);
}
```

I have tried:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt((String) list.get(0));
```

But it gives this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

I have also tried:

```
int number = (int) list.get(0);
```

But it gives this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

How can you accomplish this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use generics.    This works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String eq = "4/2+32*4*2-1";

    String[] eqList = eq.split("(?<=[+*-/])|(?=[+*-/])");

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < eqList.length; i++) {
        list.add(eqList[i]);
    }

    int a = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0));
    System.out.println(a);
}
```